# Grails 2.0.3 + JUnit 4.8.2

Tags: grails, junit

I am running Grails 2.0.3. This version uses junit 4.10 but I would to use at least the version 4.8.2. I have added as dependency the next:

```
compile 'junit:junit-dep:4.8.2' 
runtime 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
```

But it seems that it is not getting the new version. How can I delete/exclude the old version of junit??
Thanks!

Comment: You mean to say you want to downgrade from `4.10` to `4.8.2`? In the context of the question, older version is `4.8.2` and newer version is `4.10`, which one do you need? You should be able to get what you want from `4.8.2` in `4.10` (should be backward compatible).

Comment: I am really sorry!!!! You are right!!!! I do not need to downgrade to 4.8.2. It was a number confision!

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes "junit"
}

dependencies {
    test "junit:junit:4.8.2"
}
```

Answer based on [using junit 4 in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523662/using-junit-4-in-grails).
I tested it on Grail 2.1.0 and it works.